# No world frame in tf tree

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm working on two turtlebots and I have managed to make them run in the same simulation. I have gotten a TF tree that looks like this:

[image: image description]

and now I want a /world frame to connect these two robots so that I can get a better visual representation of their frames in Rviz. Wondering how I'd get a /world frame, I have seen that you can create a /map frame by using SLAM and making the turtlebot explore a map/ use localization, but is there no simpler way of doing this? I'd like to have an empty world with just a fixed frame.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/388403/no-world-frame-in-tf-tree/) by [Roshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/85346/roshan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2021-10-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can publish a static transform for each robot relative to an arbitrary `world` frame like so:

rosrun tf2_ros static_transform_publisher 0 0 0 0 0 0 world tb3_1/odom

where `0 0 0 0 0 0` is `x y z yaw pitch roll`.  See the bottom of the [Writing a tf2 static broadcaster (C++) tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf2%20static%20broadcaster%20%28C%2B%2B%29) for more information.  These transforms will anchor the odometry frames to the shared `world` frame, connecting the two tf trees.

---

Originally posted by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) with karma: 1421 on 2021-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Roshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/85346/roshan/) on 2021-10-11**:
Thank you for your answer. I tried doing it like this in my launch file:

```
  <node pkg="tf2_ros" type="static_transform_publisher" name="world_broadcast" args="1 0 0 0 0 0 1 world tb3_1/odom" />
  <node pkg="tf2_ros" type="static_transform_publisher" name="world_broadcast2" args="1 0 0 0 0 0 1 world tb3_0/odom" />
```

And while it does work, I got some of these warnings:

```
[ WARN] [1633970165.290385117, 111.748000000]: TF_REPEATED_DATA ignoring data with redundant timestamp for frame tb3_0/base_footprint at time 111,705000 according to authority /gazebo
[ WARN] [1633970165.292532905, 111.748000000]: TF_REPEATED_DATA ignoring data with redundant timestamp for frame tb3_1/base_footprint at time 111,705000 according to authority /gazebo
[ WARN] [1633970165.293894016, 111.753000000]: TF_REPEATED_DATA ignoring data with redundant timestamp for frame tb3_0/base_footprint at time 111,705000 according to authority unknown_publisher
[ WARN] [1633970165.293965629, 111.75300000
```

**Comment by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) on 2021-10-11**:
They appear unrelated to the `static_transform_publisher` nodes as the warnings reference `gazebo` and `base_footprint` transforms.  Here's a [`geometry2` issue](https://github.com/ros/geometry2/issues/467) discussing the warning.  It may indicate you have multiple publishers of the same transforms, or one publisher publishing the same transform multiple times.  Unless you suspect that the warnings *are* due to the static publishers, I would open a new question to address them.

**Comment by [Roshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/85346/roshan/) on 2021-10-11**:
I think there has to be something with the static publisher that's causing it, I've had issues like these before and they were due to problems with the tf prefixes. I fixed those by updating the ros_state_publisher and editing some files in the turtlebot gazebo model xacro to let it handle mutiple turtlebots, and the issue was completely fixed until I added the static publisher. But I'll open a new one because it could be related to the older issue and that it wasn't completely resolved

Edit:
Saw that I had `1 0 0 0 0 0 1` instead of `0 0 0 0 0 0 0`  (even though that didn't work so I used 0 0 0 0 0 0 1` ). For some reason I didn't get the warnings now.

**Comment by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) on 2021-10-11**:
I'm glad it's working!  `static_transform_publisher` can take the transform as 6 numbers (`x y z yaw pitch roll`) or 7 numbers (`x y z qx qy qz qw`).  `0 0 0 0 0 0 0` (7 zeros) would be invalid because it indicates a zero quaternion, but `0 0 0 0 0 0` (6 zeros) is valid because it indicates zero angles.  That said, I'm not sure why `0 0 0 0 0 0 1` is fine but `1 0 0 0 0 0 1` produces warnings.

**Comment by [Roshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/85346/roshan/) on 2021-10-11**:
From the warning messages it does sound like gazebo and the static transform were publishing at the same time. What I noticed is that the warnings don't show up immedietly, only after a while, and it's not spamming like it usually does with the TF_REPEATED_DATA warnings, just 4 warning messages and that's it. But in Rviz all the frames seemed right so not sure what was wrong